# Export files that created merged output of file

Tags: tfs, tfvc

There are some odd lines in the latest version of config.json and I need to analyze the content before merge, to see what went wrong with latest merge.

Assume I have $/A and $/B branches with common ancestor in changeset 1. When merging changed branches at later changeset, the common ancestor is still from changeset1.

Is there a simple `tf command` that will export config.json versions that created merged end result, meaning: config.json from both branches + common ancestor config.json file?

Actually I need this for specific changeset not only for latest. Sometimes I need to analyze past merge why it merged lines together as it did.

TFS 11.

Comment: Oh that's a tough one, as the merge is completed locally, so it's always hard to conclude why a certain merge resolution was committed. On top of that many people don't know that the 'keep mini's and 'take theirs' merge resolutions get stored marking the change as 'merged'. People should 'undo pending changes' on a file it they want to postpone merge resolution (and often pick 'keep mine instead). I'm actually not sure how to reliably replay the merge so find out what files were used as part of past resolution.

Comment: I don't need exact conflict resolution details, just the files leading to the merge. Based on merged result output file I can decipher the action chosen (keep mine, take theirs...). Manually I can select branches, but not the common ancestor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I previously wasn't aware of this extension, but it looks like it'll be very helpful in your quest:

[image]

- [Visual Studio Marketplace - Bourgeon](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=StefanLober.Bourgeon)

---

You'll need to dig into the client object model to access the details to understand this, I'm guessing all the data is there...

- [ChangesetMerge Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/bb170161(v=vs.120)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&)
- [ItemMerge Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/ff733964(v=vs.120)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&)

It contains which changeset numbers were merged and which items in that changeset were merged. From there you can find the source and target items of the merge.

But you'll need to traverse the history graph to find the common base to see where these two histories diverged originally and whether it got merges since (which would update the common parent).

- [VersionControlServer.QueryHistory Method (ItemSpec)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/hh985572(v=vs.120)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&)

You can replay a merge by creating a workspace with the source version and try merging the changeset (range) into the workspace.

```
(GetStatus status = workspace2.Merge(source, this.m_arguments.FreeArguments[1], versionRange[0], versionRange[1], this.ParseLockOption(), mergeOptions);
```

There is no command line tool for it and Visual Studio isn't really capable of visualizing the history of a single file.

```
tf vc merges A A-branched
```

Will show which changeset ranges got merges into a new changeset. This can be used to recompose the branch/merge graph.

Comment: _"You can replay a merge by creating a workspace with the source version and try merging the changeset (range) into the workspace."_ Thanks, seems like a good practice for me, unlikely something I can expect from a customer.

Comment: Thank you, the extension is for Visual Studio 2013, 2015, 2017, 2019, I need it for 2012, TFS 11.

Comment: You can connect VS 2019 or below to TFS 2012 without issues. I suspect the extension will just work. But TFS 2012 is out of support, as is Visual Studio 2012, I won't expect the author to retrofit it.

Comment: Well, I can, Customer will probably not do that. So, I need to stick with what I work with.